# Windows app ComboBox open upwards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to get a `ComoboBox` in a Windows App to open upwards instead of downwards. I've read about doing this in WPF but obviously the syntax is a little different. I've tried modifying the `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox` but I am not sure exactly what property I am supposed to be modifying.

Is there an easy way to do this for a `Windows App`?

Edit: When I try to apply Florian's fix, I get the following build error:

```
Error   1   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindName' and no extension method 'FindName' 
accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this method when the combo is loaded :

```
    private void myCombo_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlTemplate ct = this.myCombo.Template;
        Popup pop = ct.FindName("PART_Popup", this.myCombo) as Popup;
        pop.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
    }
```

Comment: I did try that, and I get compile errors on the line ct.FindName where it says it cannot resolve symbol "FindName" on ct

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Resharper. Are you using it?

Comment: I am. However I thought that the Windows App API didn't have the same available methods as normal WPF and FindName was one of the ones missing? Edit: yeah I get a compile error when I try to build with FindName. See my main post for details.

Comment: Windows App is for windows phone, so OP's [`ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209391#methods) is not the same used in [WPF windows application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)