# How to show Combobox values to up direction in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a combobox in WPF. In generally the values from combobox will populate in down/bottom direction. I have a requirement to populate in up direction. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458248/windows-app-combobox-open-upwards

Answer (score 1):

You should change the ControlTemplate for the ComboBox. Here you can find a ControlTemplate example:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates.

Look for the Popup part and change Placement from Bottom to Top.

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup"
         Placement="Top"

         <!-- more stuff here -->
/>
```